# Issue in installing firebase-admin package for python

Tags: python, firebase, pip, firebase-admin

I have recently tried to install `firebase-admin` to add in my python app via `pip install --upgrade firebase-admin`. However, I was faced with below error and I could not find the solution to fix my issue:

```
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for grpcio, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for msgpack, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: grpcio, google-api-core, google-cloud-core, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-firestore, msgpack, cachecontrol, httplib2, google-auth-httplib2, uritemplate, google-api-python-client, firebase-admin
Running setup.py install for grpcio ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
...
```

The current version of Python, I am using is `3.9` and the pip version is `20.2.3`.

Comment: It seems that the issue relates to current version of python (`3.9`). I tried with python version `3.8.6` and it is working properly.